# How can I use Tramp's SSH on Windows 10 with the native ssh.exe?

Tags: microsoft-windows, tramp, ssh

Windows 10 has its own `ssh.exe`. I can use `ssh.exe` fine within `eshell`, but not for Tramp, e.g. `/ssh:user@host:/tmp`.

Is there any way to enable Tramp with the built-in ssh (`OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can use `ssh.exe` fine within `eshell`, but not for Tramp, e.g. `/ssh:user@host:/tmp`.

Ah, but if you pay attention you will notice that the output in Eshell looks somewhat off:

```
~/ $ # within eshell
~/ $ ssh user@host
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
...
```

Since no "pseudo-terminal" is allocated, the classic PS1 is missing and TRAMP does not detect the prompt. We have to adjust the login arguments.

By default, TRAMP will supply the following arguments to `ssh`:

```lisp
(assoc 'tramp-login-args (assoc "ssh" tramp-methods))
;; => (tramp-login-args
;;     (("-l" "%u")
;;      ("-p" "%p")
;;      ("%c")
;;      ("-e" "none")
;;      ("%h")))
```

In order to force the allocation of a pseudo-terminal, we have to supply `-tt` as additional argument. I like to use `cl-pushnew` for that, but you may use whatever method you like (or even just `setf` the place):

```lisp
(when (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
  (require 'cl-lib)
  (with-eval-after-load 'tramp
    (cl-pushnew '("-tt")
                (car (alist-get 'tramp-login-args
                                (cdr (assoc "ssh" tramp-methods))))
                :test #'equal)))
```

With this, the prompt will be shown and TRAMP can work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use MS Windows. However, people have reported that Tramp's `sshx` method works on MS Windows. Something like `/sshx:user@host:/tmp`.

However, it seems like you must set `tramp-use-ssh-controlmaster-options` to `nil` first, newer Tramp versions do it for you on MS Windows.

Comment: Verified that this is also correct and works on Windows. Docs for sshx here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Inline-methods.html#index-method-sshx